# Maven, Git and Jenkins.. suggested architecture for web-app and client consumer

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, software-design

I have a J2EE web application so structured:

```
web-app (parent)
    - ejb (module)
    - war (module)
    - model (module) (distribuited on the maven repository)
    - ejb-client (module) (distribuited on the maven repository)
```

web-app is configured with **git submodules**, so for each submodule a relative project directory is created under web-app directory.

This ensure Jenkins to compile any branch correctly because web-app contains *commit hash* for relative submodules.

Before deploying web-app on the server, I deploy on the maven repository both model and ejb-client.

These dependencies are used by **a rest-client** that consumes the web app API.

The rest-client is so structured:

```
rest-client
    - ejb-client (dependency)
    - model (dependency)
```

Now I have some issues with the above structure:

1. rest-client FAILS getting ejb-client and model dependencies because they are both configured with 

       web-app

   , therefore web-app parent pom is required.

   The only solution I've adopted is to **deploy ONLY the parent pom** with

   `mvn deploy -N`

   which deploy module in no recursive way.

   Is there any way to specify directly on pom ?
2. Someone suggested me to remove models and ejb-client from the web-app and leave them as web-app dependencies,
   however I'm strong doubts about this idea because both modules are tied to web-app and Jenkins would not recognize them as submodules, 
   so even worst the hash commit that relates parent pom to its submodules would be lost.

Talking generally, what do you think about the actual structure? Is this correct or should deserve several changes ?

Comment: I would recommend to keep model and ejb-client as modules in your multi module build and do not distribute them on a different git repository so you can build your whole application in one go via `mvn package` furthermore you don't need to do things like deploy only the parent.... etc.

Comment: True for the first assertion (mvn package), false for the second one, the rest client would still fails getting dependencies because both model and ejb client are configured with parent pom

Comment: If you not deploy the artifacts to a repository manager or use a local cache as storage for dependencies (including pom's) you won't get it to work...Best would be to use a repository manager and do a `mvn deploy` on the webapp and afterwards you can use the dependencies etc. in the rest-client...

Comment: deploying a whole webapp is a bad practice at all, you have to distribuite ONLY the interfaces for the consumers

Comment: Is the webapp not deployed on a system? I bet it will be and so i don't see any "bad practice"...about that...

Comment: Is deployed on AS, but a whole web app should not deployed as a maven artifactory because it makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand. I mean to deploy all modules your web-app has to a repository manager including the pom's etc. (as usual) and than you can use them as dependencies without any problems...

Answer (score 1):

In projects like this, I usually have one parent pom with three submodules: `server` (in your case `web-app`), `common` and `client`. The `server` module houses all of the logic that is specific to the server and not required by the client. The `common` module contains all logic that is common to the server and the client and lastly, the `client` module contains the client logic. That way, the `server` module and the `client` module can both have a dependency on the `common` module.

Obviously, each module can have multiple submodules again.

Have a look at [this project](https://github.com/vatbub/tictactoe) of mine to see a working example.

**Edit:** If you have only one parent pom, you will need to deploy everything for the architecture to work. What you could do to avoid deploying the web app is to have the common and client module in one multi-module build and extract the web-app module to a different parent pom. The web app can then declare a dependency on the common module.

Comment: That is ok to me, however if client and common use the parent pom (like your project), a 3rd application that consumes the client should need the parent pom because of common and client dependency.
Take a look at issue 1 of the main question :)

Comment: Please see my edited answer

Comment: So you suggestion is to create 2 main modules, one for the web app (ejb and rest) and one for the shared parts (common and client) right ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.